# Is there a script somewhere or a way to modify excel that allows multiple selected areas to be copied and pasted?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

The motivation behind this is that in excel, after copying a segment of cells you can only highlight more cells without the ability to subtract from the selection. This annoyed me, so today I wrote a vba script to subtract from a selection the cells that were highlighted more than once. [image]
[image]

```
Sub MultiDeselect()
Dim rng As Range
Dim Uni As Range 'this is the union
Dim Intersct As Range
Dim UnionMinusIntersect As Range
Dim singleArea As Range

'MsgBox ActiveCell.Address
If Selection.Areas.Count > 1 Then
    For Each singleArea In Selection.Areas
        For Each rng In singleArea.Cells
            If Uni Is Nothing Then
                Set Uni = rng
            ElseIf Application.Intersect(Uni, rng) Is Nothing Then
                Set Uni = Union(Uni, rng)
            ElseIf Intersct Is Nothing Then
                Set Intersct = rng
            ElseIf Intersect(Intersct, rng) Is Nothing Then
                Set Intersct = Union(Intersct, rng)
            End If
        Next rng
    Next singleArea
'    MsgBox Uni.Address
    If Intersct Is Nothing Then
        Set UnionMinusIntersect = Uni
    Else
'        MsgBox Intersct.Address
        For Each singleArea In Uni
            For Each rng In singleArea.Cells
'                MsgBox rng.Address
                If Intersect(rng, Intersct) Is Nothing Then
                    If UnionMinusIntersect Is Nothing Then
                        Set UnionMinusIntersect = rng
                    Else
                        Set UnionMinusIntersect = Union(UnionMinusIntersect, rng)
                    End If
                End If
            Next rng
        Next singleArea
    End If
    'Check not null in case every cell was highlighted more than once
    If Not UnionMinusIntersect Is Nothing Then
        If UnionMinusIntersect.Cells.Count > 0 Then
            UnionMinusIntersect.Select
        End If
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Much to my dismay, after finishing, I found that copying of multiple regions is not allowed in excel which defeats my usual purpose for highlighting something. Before I try to implement a multi-copy and multi-paste, I wanted to know if someone has already done this. It would basically copy each cell relative to the top left of the selection into the corresponding cell relative to the top left of the active cell.

---

Jordan's answer works great. Here's an example of the final output:[image]

Comment: Usually what I do is just use `Value` using `Cells`with `Range`You'll have to do top, bottom, left, right if you want a hole in it though.

Comment: What about using a cross. Left to right, range. Up to down, range. Get area of intersection. Using a for each in the intersection area only and storing it into an array. Then get your desired area left to right, range, do what you want with the entire area including the intersection. Then with the array or the saved intersection area you can do or undo whatever you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two simple VB macro's.

1. Create a New Macro Enabled Workbook
2. Create the two macro's below.
3. Create add some values to some cells
4. Run **DeselectCell** macro

   - First select the entire range that you want to provide, if you're using the **Sample Excel Table** from below, you would enter: `$A$1:$F$6` and press okay.
   - Now you need to specify which cells you want to select, simply left click to specify a range. (Hold Ctrl and left click to have multiple ranges to be deselected. Example, enter: `$A$1,$C$2,$C$6` and press okay.
5. At this point, you should have an **unselect active area** like in your image above. Now just run the **CopyMultipleSelection** macro and specify into which cell you want to paste the results. In our case let's say `$A$9`, your final copied table will look like:

**Final Pasted Table**: (You'll have an empty cell instead of a _, it's only for here because of formatting issues.

```
_   4   1   2   3   4
d   a   _   6   7   8
f   9   11  1   1   121
a   21  1   12  12  sa
b   a   a   sd  a   sa
324 234 _   23  423 42
```

**Sample Excel Table**: top left is Cell A1 and bottom right is cell F6

```
1   4   1   2   3   4
d   a   5   6   7   8
f   9   11  1   1   121
a   21  1   12  12  sa
b   a   a   sd  a   sa
324 234 234 23  423 42
```

**Macros**

```
Sub DeselectCell()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim InputRng As Range
    Dim DeleteRng As Range
    Dim OutRng As Range
    xTitleId = "DeselectCell"
    Set InputRng = Application.Selection
    Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Set DeleteRng = Application.InputBox("Delete Range", xTitleId, Type:=8)
    For Each rng In InputRng
        If Application.Intersect(rng, DeleteRng) Is Nothing Then
            If OutRng Is Nothing Then
                Set OutRng = rng
            Else
                Set OutRng = Application.Union(OutRng, rng)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    OutRng.Select
End Sub

Sub CopyMultipleSelection()
    Dim SelAreas() As Range
    Dim PasteRange As Range
    Dim UpperLeft As Range
    Dim NumAreas As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim TopRow As Long, LeftCol As Integer
    Dim RowOffset As Long, ColOffset As Integer
    Dim NonEmptyCellCount As Integer
' Exit if a range is not selected
    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then
        MsgBox "Select the range to be copied. A multiple selection is allowed."
        Exit Sub
    End If
' Store the areas as separate Range objects
    NumAreas = Selection.Areas.Count
    ReDim SelAreas(1 To NumAreas)
    For i = 1 To NumAreas
        Set SelAreas(i) = Selection.Areas(i)
    Next
' Determine the upper left cell in the multiple selection
    TopRow = ActiveSheet.Rows.Count
    LeftCol = ActiveSheet.Columns.Count
    For i = 1 To NumAreas
        If SelAreas(i).Row < TopRow Then TopRow = SelAreas(i).Row
        If SelAreas(i).Column < LeftCol Then LeftCol = SelAreas(i).Column
    Next
    Set UpperLeft = Cells(TopRow, LeftCol)
' Get the paste address
    On Error Resume Next
    Set PasteRange = Application.InputBox _
    (Prompt:="Specify the upper left cell for the paste range:", _
    Title:="Copy Mutliple Selection", _
    Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
' Exit if canceled
    If TypeName(PasteRange) <> "Range" Then Exit Sub
' Make sure only the upper left cell is used
    Set PasteRange = PasteRange.Range("A1")
' Check paste range for existing data
    NonEmptyCellCount = 0
    For i = 1 To NumAreas
        RowOffset = SelAreas(i).Row - TopRow
        ColOffset = SelAreas(i).Column - LeftCol
        NonEmptyCellCount = NonEmptyCellCount + _
        Application.CountA(Range(PasteRange.Offset(RowOffset, ColOffset), _
        PasteRange.Offset(RowOffset + SelAreas(i).Rows.Count - 1, _
        ColOffset + SelAreas(i).Columns.Count - 1)))
  Next i
' If paste range is not empty, warn user
  If NonEmptyCellCount <> 0 Then _
        If MsgBox("Overwrite existing data?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, _
        "Copy Multiple Selection") <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
' Copy and paste each area
  For i = 1 To NumAreas
    RowOffset = SelAreas(i).Row - TopRow
    ColOffset = SelAreas(i).Column - LeftCol
    SelAreas(i).Copy PasteRange.Offset(RowOffset, ColOffset)
  Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: @Máté Juhász least you can do if you're going to remove my comment for the correct answer is upvote it so i can get 10 reputation to be able to comment.

Comment: There ya go :) Welcome!